# Interactive map in HTML,CSS,JS is jolting whenever I hover over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Afternoon all, I have an interactive map that is intended to be used for keeping track of locations within the UK, so when someone hovers their mouse over a selected area or dot on the map then they will be given information.

The code for the map is as followed, this is a mixture of HTML, CSS and jQuery to achieve the results required.

I have embedded this code within the following link as it is, quite long..however you can see the map there also! Enjoy.

https://jsbin.com/tiyacimufu/edit?html,output

Really look forward to hearing from someone! <3

Comment: It jumps because you hide and show the `#map-tip` element

Comment: Yeah. If you comment out `$('#map-tip').show().html(map_config[id]['hover']);` you'll no longer see it jump.

Comment: Rory, Andy.

Please may I extend my thanks to you massively.

Thankyou!